# ilog.rules.teamserver.model.impl.IlrProjectInfoSummaryImpl;incompatible types for field isDecisionService

Tags: rules, rule-engine, ibm-odm

We are migrating ODM 8.8 to IBM ODM 8.9.2. I am aware that Classic Rule Engine is deprecated from IBM ODM 8.9.2 but is there any way to use this to extract rules. 
I'm facing below error while using Rule Engine as Classic Rule Engine in IBM ODM 8.9.2.

Error:  java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not deserialize result from HTTP invoker remote service [<>]; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: ilog.rules.teamserver.model.impl.IlrProjectInfoSummaryImpl; incompatible types for field isDecisionService.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to migrate from DE to CRE in my current version of ODM, then upgrade to the new version. Of course, that could vary depending on your exact use of ODM. You will have to move to DE in any case, but doing it that way avoids making two sets of changes at one time. Version 8.8 still has some restrictions on using DE (every release has fewer, 8.9.2 none at all), but most likely you would not run into any of them. The rules themselves don't actually change much from CRE to DE, it's mostly just procedures, features, and capabilities that are different.